# PyGTK widget opacity

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

Is there any way to set a widget's opacity in PyGTK?
I know there's a function for windows:

```
gtk.Window.set_opacity(0.85)
```

but there seems to be no equivalent for arbitrary widgets.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what do you want to see "through" the widget you want to make translucent? the desktop/other windows? or another widget in your application?

Comment: Basically, I want the desktop/other windows to be seen. I currently have a custom expose event handler to make the window background semitransparent (I draw this with Cairo), which works very well, but I don't know if there's a way to do something similar with normal GTK+ widgets.

Answer (score 3):

[From pygtk reference](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--set-opacity):

> For setting up per-pixel alpha, see `gtk.gdk.Screen.get_rgba_colormap()`. For making non-toplevel windows translucent, see `gtk.gdk.Window.set_composited()`.

Comment: That will still depend on it being a widget that has its own GdkWindow

Comment: No if you'd like to set per-pixel alpha channel.  This would be very difficult to implement correctly, however.

Comment: I will add to this that alpha channels on gtk windows don't work in Windows systems...only Unix.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth looking into [pygtkglext](http://www.k-3d.org/gtkglext/Main_Page) for fancier widget stuff.